# Consistent Missing Right Parenthesis Error

Tags: sql, oracle, casting

I'm trying to right a query that checks if the value is a number and I keep getting a

> ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

error no matter what I do.

Even these queries return the error:

```
SELECT CAST(123456  AS NUMBER(1,0) DEFAULT -1 ON CONVERSION ERROR)
  FROM ANY_TABLE_NAME
```

```
SELECT VALIDATE_CONVERSION('99' AS NUMBER)
  FROM ANY_TABLE_NAME
```

Anything I can do to solve this?

I'm using Oracle SQL Developer version *20.2.1.175*

Comment: What is the version of your Oracle database? (Not your SQL Developer version as that is just the user interface you are using and is nothing to do with the database version). Cannot replicate the error in Oracle 18g [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=ce9aebb97dc0f370c03c3984f351a44b)

Comment: You've given the SQL Developer client version, but what is your database version? [Error handling for `cast()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/newft/new-features.html#GUID-03517A06-2AA8-4EE5-9A20-B76E519EB69C) and [`validate_conversion()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/newft/new-features.html#GUID-E4F74104-0A29-4910-AFC1-28D5F6E6D11C) were both added in 12cR2 (12.2), so they will error in earlier versions.

Comment: Ok, so that was the problem. I'm using 11.2. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

`VALIDATE_CONVERSION` was not introduced until Oracle 12.2.

`CAST` also did not get the error handling extension until Oracle 12.2.

Therefore, if you are using Oracle 12.1 or earlier then those functions will not be valid.

For example:

- They fail in [Oracle 11g db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=ce9aebb97dc0f370c03c3984f351a44b)
- The work in [Oracle 18g db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=ce9aebb97dc0f370c03c3984f351a44b)

*Note: this is the Oracle database version and not the version of SQL Developer, which is just a front-end user interface for accessing the database.*

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem. I'm using Oracle 11.2.

Answer (score 0):

```
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
```

This error belongs to generic error messages, indicating one or more syntax errors.

**How to debug ?**

- it means we have omitted a right bracket.
  *(to verify,  you can use an editor which allows a "match bracket" control)*
- it means the compiler received an **"out of context"** keyword.
- it means a misspelled word (i.e a missing comma, a space instead of an underscore,etc )

Your sinthax seems to be right.
You're (probably) facing an "**out of context**" keyword.